# Assemble data list to send between screens

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having trouble putting together a list of a class I created by taking information from an AsyncSnapshot.

My code is using a FutureBuilder and getting a dynamic list of items as shown in the image below:

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgiC9.png)

So I created the following class to hold these values:

```
class TesteListaTopicos {
  int? id;
  int? idVideo;
  String? titulo;
  String? tipoMidia;
  String? tipoMidiaDetalhe;

  TesteListaTopicos({this.id, this.idVideo, this.tipoMidia,
      this.tipoMidiaDetalhe, this.titulo});
}
```

I want to create a list of TesteListaTopicos:

```
var topicosList = List<TesteListaTopicos>;
```

But I don't know how to pass the values to the list. I access the snapshot values as follows:

```
String title = (snapshot.data.listaTopicoVideo[index].titulo);
int id = (snapshot.data.listaTopicoVideo[index].id);
int idVideo = (snapshot.data.listaTopicoVideo[index].idVideo);
```

Could someone help me how do I store the values in the class?
My goal with storing all values in a class and to send that class later to another screen, using Navigator.push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you have a `fromJson` constructor or method which converts the Json to the `TesteListaTopicos` object like this:

```
TesteListaTopicos.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : 
  id = json["id"],
  idVideo = json["idVideo"],
  tipoMidia = json["tipoMidia"],
  tipoMidiaDetalhe = json["tipoMidiaDetalhe"],
  titulo = json["titulo"];
```

Then you can map the list `listaTopicoVideo` to a list of `TesteListaTopicos` like this:

```
List<TesteListaTopicos> topicosList = snapshot.data.listaTopicoVideo
  .map((element) => TesteListaTopicos.fromJson(element))
  .toList();
```